# how to increase size of post parameter list

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

Post works with array length 20 but not working with array length 2000:

js/anglular

```
  $http.post('/index/SaveArray', $scope.SaveList).then(
                function successCallback(response) {},
                function errorCallback(response) {}
  );
```

C#

```
  public ActionResult SaveArray(List<SelectModel> dataToSave)
  {
      StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
      JsonResult objResult = new JsonResult();
      return Json(objResult, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add this key to App Setting tag in the web.config file.
this setting increase elements allowed to deserialize.

```
 <appSettings>
        <add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="2147483644" />
 </appSettings>
```